# Is running a Linux container on windows AWS instance possible?

Tags: linux, windows, amazon-web-services, docker, virtualization

I'm trying to run a Linux (ubuntu LTS) container inside a windows server 2019 OS. The problem is that the windows OS runs as an AWS instance.

There have been problem for me trying to achieve this and I've been reading somewhat different opinions on the internet regarding whether or not it is possible. Some say it will be possible on a .metal instance which is bare metal. Currently I've been trying running it on a regular t3 instance with has virtualization type HVM.

To sum up my questions are:

1. Is running a linux container on windows aws instance possible?
2. If yes, how?
3. If not, will it be possible on a bare metal instance?

Please keep in mind that I need the container to run in a Windows environment due to multiple tasks the the OS needs to achieve (and I don't want multiple instances)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to use Docker Desktop on Windows, you need either Hyper-V or Windows Susbsystem for Linux enabled (which at its turn requires Hyper-V). Both solutions demand of VT-x capabilities, but you're running inside a VM, which means that is not so easy to achieve.

It is called "nested virtualization", and it is not supported in common EC2 virtual machines. ([source](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=926556))

You can certainly run Linux containers on a bare metal Windows instance (but why you should? it is way cheaper and simpler to create a Linux virtual machine on EC2 and communicate it with your Windows host). Should still that be your purpose, you can install [Windows Server 2019 with Hyper-V](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/Amazon-Web-Services-Microsoft-Windows-Server-2019-/B07RJTTGML). ([tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/es/blogs/compute/running-hyper-v-on-amazon-ec2-bare-metal-instances/))

Another alternative for SMALL, SMALL things, that *could* work without nested virtualization (I haven't tried), would be using WSL1. ([more info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10))

WSL1 uses a compatibility layer between Windows and Linux system calls, without actually virtualizing the operating system. [Some folks](https://medium.com/faun/docker-running-seamlessly-in-windows-subsystem-linux-6ef8412377aa) have been able to install Docker 17.09 on WSL1, but this is a very adventurous path I would not recommend taking.